# Android - how to automatically re-size the images on different screen

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview

i am getting fixed image size on display as its shows normal in tab but in smaller screen it stayed on original size.

i have tried different ways but no luck

i m posting XML please have a look thanks

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Item1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/img_A1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Provide weightsum attribute to your linear layout and give it value 100 and give the weight to your imageview that is 50 or 60. Also give the height of image to 0 dp.

Comment: on layout it shows fine but doesn't work as required on smaller screen phone :(

Answer (score 3):

android doesnt resizes the images on its own. instead it takes different images from drawable resource for different screen sizes phones.

```
ldpi- is for the lower resolutions image phones
mdpi- for medium level density pixels phones
hdpi- for higher density pixels phones
xdpi-for high resolution phones.
xxdpi- for more high resolution phones.
```

you have to store the image with same name but with different sizes in these folders so that android can take up the relevant image according to the screen size and resolution.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, Android does not resize the image. You have to do it manually. You can use

```
scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
```

Once you get the image resized, you can call

```
item1.setImageBitmap(scaledBmp);
```